# How to know if a world point is inside a box given by position (Vector3), scale (Vector3) and rotation (Quaternion)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an object whose Transform's position, rotation and scale represents the position, rotation and scale of a box/cube.

I want to know if a world point given by a `Vector3` is inside this box representation.

I am able to tell where is this virtual box by attaching a Cube with default propotions as children of it, or by using the following gizmo:

```cs
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, transform.rotation, transform.localScale);
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(Vector3.zero, Vector3.one);
}
```

I want to say if a world position (eg.: `new Vector3(0.98f, 3.2f, 1.26f)` is inside or outside the area the gizmo will draw.

#### What did I try?

- I know it could be easily solved using colliders, eg. `BoxCollider.ClosestPoint`, but in my scenario I will create lots of GameObject at runtime to represent a "labirynth" map, and they should not have colliders because there is no point in the map having Physics and it could interfere with other parts of the game.
- The drawn mesh or bounds of a mesh render may not match exactly the box I want to test. The visual representation may differ from the logic, so I can't use it either.
- I tried to use `thatObjectWithGizmo.InverseTransformPoint(myWorldPoint)` in expectation it would convert from world to local, and tested this way:

```cs
public class ScriptToTestPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform thatObjectWithGizmo;
    public Vector3 myWorldPoint;

    public void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Vector3 resultingPosition = thatObjectWithGizmo.InverseTransformPoint(myWorldPoint);
        bool isInside = new Bounds(thatObjectWithGizmo.position, thatObjectWithGizmo.lossyScale).Contains(resultingPosition);

        Gizmos.color = isInside ? Color.red : Color.white;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position, 1f);
    }
}
```

But it gave me wrong results.

How can I do this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me! After some trial and error trying to realize why the results were working when the box was at default position, but not when moving and rotating, it turns out that everything is ok, but I tested the point against the world position and scale of the object (bonus: I ignored its rotation).

It seems the line:

```cs
Vector3 resultingPosition = thatObjectWithGizmo.InverseTransformPoint(myWorldPoint);
```

is correctly converting the world point to a local point, but I misunderstood how I should check it, by testing it against world position:

```cs
// Wrong
bool isInside = new Bounds(thatObjectWithGizmo.position, thatObjectWithGizmo.lossyScale).Contains(resultingPosition);
```

The fix is simple, I need to test against a local Bounds:

```cs
// Correct
bool isInside = new Bounds(Vector3.zero, Vector3.one).Contains(resultingPosition);
```

This way it will give the information I want with precision.